# ngx-charts legend position is wrong

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

Hello to all developers,

I have been working with ngx-charts to do my charts, so far everything is good but when i try to move the position of the legend to below, its like it goes beyond the boundaries of the chart and no matter what I do I can't see it properly and there is a space reserved to the side as if it were going to be placed there.

I share a bit of the code I was using and a small image to sample.

```
<div class="widget-body">
   <div class="clearfix" style="height: 450px; padding: 0px">
      <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner fa-5x center-spinner" *ngIf="salesSpinner == true"></i>
      <ngx-charts-line-chart *ngIf="salesSpinner == false"
         [scheme]="colorScheme"
         [results]="salesData"
         [legend]="legend"
         legendPosition="below"
         [xAxis]="showXAxis"
         [yAxis]="showYAxis"
         [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
         [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
         [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel1"
         [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel1">
         </ngx-charts-line-chart>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you see the link below you will notice the legend is out of boundaries and not showing.

[Chart image](https://gyazo.com/b3e94590e1d78c6c75c517a5a4568bf1)

Comment: Hi,
the legend Position = "below" feature doesn't work for me. Could you tell me how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

add it to styles.css or any global css file

```
ngx-charts-legend {
  display: block !important;
}
```